# What would be the best way of continuing the wall around the corner?

Tags: modeling

Very new to Blender. Lots to learn. Eager to learn it.

In this example, what methods would you suggest for continuing the wall and matching it to the angles of the floor corner?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a loop cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) on  the floor, and slide it to set the width of the wall. (While sliding, hitting <kbd>E</kbd> will make the new loop parallel to one side of the cut faces, and hitting <kbd>F</kbd> will flip which side.) Then extrude upwards.

[image]